# How to exit outer function early from one of many inner non-blocking function calls?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, nonblocking

I'm writing a naive implementation of [async.parallel](https://github.com/caolan/async#parallel) as a learning exercise. Here is the description from the docs:

> **parallel(tasks, [callback])**  Run the tasks array of functions in
>   parallel, without waiting until the previous function has completed.
>   If any of the functions pass an error to its callback, the main
>   callback is immediately called with the value of the error. Once the
>   tasks have completed, the results are passed to the final callback as
>   an array.

I'm not sure **how to exit early**, in the event that one of the functions returns with an error. I'm passing the callback an error, but of course the other functions continue executing.

Below is what I have so far; feel free to try it out on your machine.

```
function parallel(tasks, cb) {
  cb = cb || function() {};

  if (!Array.isArray(tasks)) return cb('tasks must be an array');  
  if (!tasks.length) return cb();

  var res = [];
  var completed_count = 0;

  for (var i=0; i<tasks.length; i++) {
    (function(ind) {
      tasks[ind](function(err, val) {
    if (err) return complete(err); // <--- ! 
    res[ind] = val;
    completed_count++;
    if (completed_count === tasks.length) complete(null, res);
      });
    } (i));
  }
};


// ===== test functions =====
function slow(time, cb) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    cb(null, time);
  }, time);
};

function slowError(time, cb) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    cb('Some Error', time);
  }, time);
}

function complete(err, results) {
  if (err) return console.log(err);
  else return console.log(results);
};


// ===== tests =====
// should return [1000, 2000, 3000]
parallel([slow.bind(null, 1000),
          slow.bind(null, 2000),
          slow.bind(null, 3000)], complete);

// should exit early
parallel([slowError.bind(null, 1000),
          slowError.bind(null, 2000),
          slow.bind(null, 3000)], complete);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but of course the other functions continue executing

Yes. And you cannot do anything against that, since they don't offer you a way to cancel them. `async.js` doesn't do anything either, you just have to let them run.

> I'm not sure how to exit early

But "letting them run" doesn't mean you have to wait for them. You can just fire the callback right away - which is the "immediate" exit they're talking about.

---

Some points in your implementation which you didn't get quite right:

- make sure that in no - absolutely no - way you call the `callback` multiple times. Users expect that from you, and their apps will run crazy if you fail to do.
- you should be able to cope with tasks that don't get this right either, and call your function expressions multiple times
- reiterating point #1: further errors are supposed to be ignored
- you might want to prevent memory leaks and garbage collect your result array when you're done, even if some tasks still hold references to your function expressions

I'll leave those as an exercise to you :-)

Answer (score 1):

You have to store the state of the whole execution in `parallel` function, and check this on every callback: should be the state in errored/finished state each next callback should be dismissed. Something like this:

```
function parallel(tasks, cb) {
  var result = [];
  var await = tasks.length;
  tasks.forEach(function(task, i){
    task(function(err, val){
      if (await === 0) return;
      if (err) {
        await = 0;
        cb(err);
        return;
      }
      result[i] = val;
      if (--await === 0) cb(null, result);
    })
  });
}
```

Here I'm using the countdown to match the end or completed state. You can also use an `errored` boolean flag for instance, or anything you want to save the state and check it on every callback.